# Bootstrap sidebar item hidden issue on multiple hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As shown in below screenshot, can be noticed [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) on **getbootstrap.com** by lowering the browser height. As sidebar is fixed there for when height of sidebar increases specially in case of multiple hierarchies it starts hiding items underneath it. And page scroll do nothing to show the hidden items.

How can I overcome this issue?

[image]

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn I have improved the question, it would be great if you give me suggestions further to improve it or edit it by yourself to improve. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable scrollbar to side panel so user can scroll for hidden menus.
you need to fix visible height of window to sidebar container.